# How to declare a variable outside of a try catch and for each loop

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

[exception handling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Uwv.png)I am a newbie writing code for my c# class. We have to display exception handling but I ran into a red squiggly on my "lines" variable in my for each loop because I put a try catch around the method i declared lines in. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

I tried looking for similar issues on other forum with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the variable `lines` before `try` block, like this:

```cs
string[] lines = new string[0];
try {
   lines = File.ReadAllText(txtFile);
}
catch (Exception e) {
//....
}

//...

foreach (var line in lines) {
//...
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Prefer using `Array.Empty<T>` or `Enumerable.Empty<T>` instead of `new T[0]` to instantiate empty array/collection variable.

Comment: No! When you declare a variable, you don't need to initialize it. By initializing it, you are simply creating garbage that needs to be cleaned up and preventing the compiler from warning you if you don't properly Invalides it before you use it. Just use `string[] lines;`. If you get a nullable warning, `string[]? lines;` or `string[]! lines;`

Comment: @Flydog57, OP has `foreach` loop on `lines` after `try-catch` blocks. Unitialized `lines` variable leads to error

Comment: I had added my comments about it to @Flydog57 response, but looks like he removed it, and disliked my answer. So, my suggestion was:"Attached example does not contain throw/return at catch block. When we have an exception, we'll log it and execution will be continued. This case has two solutions: if we want to continue - we have to initialize `lines` var as a empty array. But, we can skip initialisation, but we need stop execution in `catch` block"

Comment: I didn't downvote. But, if you don't initialize `lines` (as I suggest) then the reference to `lines` in the foreach loop will not compile. At that point, the programmer has to ask "why am I iterating over a collection that may not have been initialized?" That's kinda-sorta my point. Maybe you want to have an empty collection (in that case, perhaps it makes sense to initialize it to empty in the catch - it makes the intention clearer)